# Postgresql order by first column, but with nulls or zeros in second column last

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How to sort a table with multiple columns where sort is alphabetic by first column but all the alphabetic entries that have nulls or zeros in the second column  appear last.

Before sort
Table "user"

```
username    monies    zip
jim         25       87888
allan       12       34333
adrian       0       97677
abel       null      87888
will         4       88788
```

After the sort
Table "user"

```
username    monies    zip
allan       12       34333
jim         25       87888
will         4       88788
abel       null      87888
adrian       0       97677
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
 SELECT 
     * 
 FROM 
     "user"
 ORDER BY 
     name ASC, 
     monies nulls last
```

Comment: you can use `nullif(monies, 0)` to treat zero as `null`

Comment: Thanks for correction. I added nulls to the table above..

Comment: you wrote name DESC  in query but in after sort they are ASC?

Comment: Thanks for correction lat long it should be ASC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the sorting for `0` or `null` first and then do the alphabetic sort by username

```
order by case when monies = 0  or monies is null then 1 else 0 end,  username
```